# What is causing an attribute error in my geocode?

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I’m trying to get latitude and longitude based on a full address column. The address column is an object type. When I apply the geocode only on the first 10 rows of my address column as a test, it runs fine with no error. But when I apply my function to the whole column I get an

> attribute error: ‘float’ object has no attribute ‘encode’

```
geolocater = MapBox(api_key=‘’)
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

df[‘geo_address’] = df[‘address’].apply(geocode)
```

Comment: Please remember to turn off "smart quotes" when you post code. You have the wrong types of quotes in the code snippet.

Comment: Please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.